# JSON to HTML not rendering into HTML via ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using PHPstorm IDE and i'm trying to render the following JSON and it gets stuck showing only the `<ul></ul>` without spitting the `<li>'s` into HTML the each function. Any idea what could be the issue?

thanks.

**Script.js:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function (){
        //fetch json file
        $.ajax({
            url:'data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    items.push('<li id=" ' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                });
                $('<ul/>', {
                    'class': 'tasks',
                    html: items.join('')
                }).appendTo('body');
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function(){
                    alert('there was a problem with the server. try again in a few secs');
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**And the JSON:**

```
{"id":"1","mesi":"mesima 0","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"2","mesi":"mesima 1","done_bool":"0"},{"id":"3","mesi":"mesima 2 ","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"4","mesi":"mesima 3","done_bool":"1"}
```

My HTML is just an a href that spits out the click ID:

`<a href="#" id="clickme">Get JSON</a>`

Comment: If your data is one dimension array for single element, than `,each(data)` will generate wrong `items` array.

Comment: Not really on topic, but just a general bit of advice: jQuery has a $.map function that you can use instead of the $.each. It will save you from having to manually create the array. More info here:  https://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: First, where is the method GET or POST you must specify one.
Second use ``map`` instead of ``$.each`` because you are handling an **array of objects** and not a **single object**.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
success: function(data){
            var items = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                items += '<li id=" ' + key + '">' + val + '</li>';
            });
            ul = $('<ul/>').html(items);
             $('body').append(ul);
        }
```

for multiple objects

```
success: function(datas){
            var items = '';
           $.each(datas, function (i,data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    items += '<li id=" ' + key + '">' + val + '</li>';
                });
            });
            ul = $('<ul/>').html(items);
             $('body').append(ul);
        }
```

output

```
<ul>
    <li id=" id">1</li>
    <li id=" mesi">mesima 0</li>
    <li id=" done_bool">1</li>
    <li id=" id">2</li>
    <li id=" mesi">mesima 1</li>
    .
    .
</ul>
```

Comment: Yet only one issue, if the JSON has more than 1 object in them, it would render only the last object, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: pls check edited answer. Is this what you expected or I am getting it wrong ?

Comment: I can't open link ( blocked ). You got output ?

Comment: the link is just my printscreen. in anycase it sets every li to a letter, it's disastrous lol :P please look at the link for the screenshot.

Comment: The edited answer has output. Is that what u want or else post expected output in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
```

By Using this Method You can Easily get Your JSON value In HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :)

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                var html = "<ul>";
                items = data.map(function(obj){
                   html += "<li id='" + obj.id + "'>" + obj.mesi + "</li";
                });
                html += "</ul>";

                $('body').append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with some like this

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function (){
        //fetch json file
        $.ajax({
            url:'data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                // uncomment line below if data is a single JSON     
                // data = [data]

                var items = [];

                // we create a list where we will append the items
                var list = document.createElement("ul");

                data.forEach(function(item){

                    // we create a list item 
                    var listItem = document.createElement("li");

                    // we set the attributes
                    listItem.setAttribute("id", item.id ); // item.id or the property that you need 

                    // we add text to the item
                    listItem.textContent = item.mesi;

                    // We append the list item to the list
                    list.appendChild(listItem);

                });
                // we append the list to the body
                $("body").html(list);

            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function(){
                    alert('there was a problem with the server. try again in a few secs');
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks. I triedf but it doesn't work, it returns :  it returns an arror: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function for this line: data.forEach(function(item){

Comment: Nice to help you! The best way for thanking in StackOverflow is marking the answer as useful or as the best answer!

Comment: if data is an array, it has to work. If data is not array, you should tell us what datatype is for improving my answer and adapt it at your case

Comment: I have updated my answer take into account that `data` may not be an array

Answer (score 0):

> Try like this:

```
 $(function() {
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        // fetch json file
        $.ajax({
            url : 'data.json',
            dataType : 'json',
            // please confirm request type is GET/POST
            type : 'GET',
            success : function(data) {
                // please check logs in browser console
                console.log(data);
                var ulHtml = "<ul>";
                $.each(data, function(key, obj) {
                    ulHtml += '<li id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.mesi + '</li>';
                });
                ulHtml += "</ul>";
                // please check logs in browser console
                console.log(ulHtml);
                $('body').append(ulHtml);
            },
            error : function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
});


<button id="clickme">Get JSON data</button>
```

> I log json data and created ul html, Please check logs in browser console

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to output each item, so I made a simple suggestion, you can easily change the HTML to what you need. Here is working code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="clickme">Get JSON</a>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    //fetch json file
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {            
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          // the HTML output for each item
          var done = (val.done_bool === '1') ? 'true' : 'false';
          items.push('<li id=" ' + val.id + '">' + val.mesi + ': ' + done + '</li>');
        });
        $('<ul/>', {
          'class': 'tasks',
          html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
      },
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert('there was a problem with the server. try again in a few secs');
        }
      }
    });

  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

data.json

```
[{"id":"1","mesi":"mesima 0","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"2","mesi":"mesima 1","done_bool":"0"},{"id":"3","mesi":"mesima 2 ","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"4","mesi":"mesima 3","done_bool":"1"}]
```

**I also created a __jsfiddle__ so you can test it directly.** (The AJAX call is simulated with the Mockjax library): https://jsfiddle.net/dh60nn5g/

Good to know:
If you are trying to load the JSON from another domain, you may need to configure CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the help. I am using on my local pc with XAMPP and the please check the JSON object again (I edited) please let me know if the code is returning multiple li's rather than the last one

Comment: @erezT: after your edit, the data is **no longer valid JSON**! Currently it's only a comma-separated list of 4 separate JSON objects...  
See [The JSON specification](http://www.json.org). To fix the error, surround your list with a pair of square brackets:
`[{"id":"1","mesi":"mesima 0","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"2","mesi":"mesima 1","done_bool":"0"},{"id":"3","mesi":"mesima 2 ","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"4","mesi":"mesima 3","done_bool":"1"}]`. When in doubt, always test your JSON data at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com). I will edit my answer to work with the new (fixed) data.

Comment: @erezT: Please review my answer again, now it's edited to use your extended data (with fixed syntax). Test the jsfiddle link and see it in action. Copy and paste the code into your project, it works. If you like the answer, please mark it as useful or as the best answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this supposed to be a GET request? i think you are missing the method on your Ajax request. You should add

```
method: 'GET'
```

to your ajax request. I think this is a big deal in making ajax request.

Comment: To change the HTTP verb, use the `type` option, but it is not needed as "GET" is the default.

Comment: i just though because he was getting and empty array he was not getting data at all. So the request is not getting data. That was my point, but tnx for negative, so kind.